# Chown permission not allowed while restoring from LTO drive

Tags: chown

i have to restore some file to my network system from LTO Tape, i use bru command to restore the file. but it is giving an error message chown permission not permited.

Comment: did you sudo chown? what user/network user make the original backup?

Comment: the shared folder is shared with root user of the network system.